# Can one's future self cause one's past self to have a Force vision?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

Mastery of the Force can lead to many fantastical things, such as empathic and telepathic abilities, telekinesis, life extension, and the ability to predict the future to some extent (so-called "Force visions").

From a certain point of view, *seeing the future* is an exchange of information, from future to past.  **Is it possible to use the Force to send information from the present to the past — say, to one's past self, with the goal of altering events that have occurred?**

Put differently:

**Can one's future self consciously cause one's past self to have a Force vision?**

If such a thing is possible, is there an example of it in occuring in any *Star Wars* material?  Perhaps in the extended universe?

**UPDATE:** Apparently, it is possible to *travel through time* using the Force:

**[Wikia: Force Storm (wormhole)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_storm_%28wormhole%29)**

If this is correct, then the above question could be reduced to **"Can one induce a Force vision in another person?"**  If the answer is *yes*, then one could induce a Force vision in one's past self via a Force Storm wormhole, making the answer to the original question "yes" as well!

Comment: Speculation:  Seeing the future and communicating with people who are in the future (relative to yourself) are two different things.  A Jedi can see the future, but not interact with it (until it becomes the present). Note that Luke has to actually go to Bespin to save his friends.  If he could just tell future-Han not to trust Lando, he could have stayed on Dagobah.  So the parallel to that would be that a Jedi can see the past, but not interact with it.  However, the same is true for non-Jedi too.  It isn't a special power, it is just memory.

Comment: @WadCheber : I understand the parallel you are setting up ("from a certain point of view")...although the question still stands, can it / has it been done?  :-)

Comment: Also, I think the Jedi would have to focus on the communication - both the past version of himself and the future version of himself would need to concentrate on the conversation.  But the past version has no way of knowing that a conversation is supposed to happen.  It would be like the Doc in Back to the Future knowing that he should wear a bulletproof vest in the first 1985 timeline without Marty ever telling him to do so.

Comment: @WadCheber : The idea isn't so much one of conversation, but rather that information appears in the recipient's mind that wasn't there before...hopefully advantageous information.  The recipient didn't seek it...the future self of the recipient sent it.

Comment: I still think it would be like using walkie talkies.  If you don't know someone is going to send a message, you don't know that you should turn your walkie talkie on to receive the message.  Future you is talking into his walkie talkie, but past you is sitting on the toilet reading a magazine, and his walkie talkie is in a drawer with dead batteries in it.

Comment: @WadCheber : I've never had a vision, but I (hope) I'd know if I were having one.  :-)

Comment: It's a great question. I'll be looking forward to seeing the answers.

Comment: @WadCheber : Thanks.  I am too (obviously)!  :-)

Comment: @Praxis How would you know that information had just magically appeared in your mind as opposed to a normal thought. And once it was there, you would already know it and so how would you then know to send it back at the right time? "I don't need to tell my past self that because I already knew that then."

Comment: @Alarion : You wouldn't necessarily *need* to distinguish between information sent back to you and a normal thought.  All that is important is that you have the information now and can act differently because of it.

Comment: At least in canon time travel is not introduced in star wars yet. And changing the past is clearly a time travel theme (also if it is achieved by time communication). The force vision seems not to be something your future self sent to you. Otherwise the visions will only focus on yourself, will not reach past your death (greate prophecy) and you can't have visions from things, where you are not present (Yoda about Lukes try to save his friends). So it seems to be vision of possible futures not tied in any way to yourself.

Comment: @Hothie : If you back that up with research / references, that could easily become an answer.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Legends canon, Jacen Solo used [Flow Walking](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Flow-walking) to observe past and future events, and to a small extent influence past events and people.  He taught the technique to Tahiri, who accidently and momentarily caught the attention of Anakin Solo during an earlier mission (though he did not realize it was her).  So, while I don't know if it is possible to induce full visions in people of the past, it has been shown that they can be "nudged" or otherwise affected through the Force across time.